# Automatically pick the p-value from MASS::glmmPQL

Tags: r

I want to automatically pick the p-value from this model:

```
otu1 <- glmmPQL(X577110~treat,random=~1|time,family=poisson,data=otu)
```

since I will be running 1000 of these models, it's better to be able to automatically pick the p-value. I tried `summary(otu1)$p-value` and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something like this?  These are the only p-values I can find in the summary output ...

```
library("MASS")
ss <- summary(glmmPQL(y ~ trt + week, random = ~ 1 | ID,
              family = binomial, data = bacteria))
```

You can use `names(ss)`, `str(ss)` to search through the summary object for components you might be interested in.

```
print(ss$tTable[,"p-value"])
 ##   (Intercept)      trtdrug     trtdrug+         week 
 ##  2.192186e-09 5.395735e-02 2.091910e-01 3.057753e-04
```